# How to to move 4 million customer records from one subsidiary to other subsidiary via script in netsuite?

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am a newbie at Net Suite scripting. I need move 4 million records customer data from one subsidiary to another subsidiary Via Net suite script. I also created saved search for that particular records. IN CSV imports it took more time. is  it possible to move via script?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code forum. Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: @soviut first of all you know Netsuite?

Comment: No, your question is too vague which is a good way to get it closed.

Comment: If you know netsuite. You never ask those type of comments.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is doing it through CSV as it will take longer to do so using script. If you have multiple queues, you may want to activate multithreading on the CSV options.

Comment: is it possible in script? if possible means please share sample script. Thanks

Comment: @user7114323 no one is going to just give you a script. Try something and then come back with questions.

Answer (score 1):

Use suitescript 2.0 map reduce script. It will auto reschedule the script and it is much faster

Answer (score 0):

As @Soviut said, please share the code that you already have and have tried.

@Adolfo is correct, though, in that it will probably be faster doing this via CSV import.

If your customers have any transactions, you will have to unlink them first, as the record can not be moved between subsidiaries if it has transactions associated with it.

Comment: please tell in schedule script how many data can be moved out of 40 lakhs

Comment: That is not an answerable question.  A scheduled script has two items that it can run until they are met.
Time Limit: 3600 seconds & Usage Limit: 10000 units.

Comment: actually i am fresher in net-suite. Using Webservices can i move this data?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with web services.  Post the code that you are currently using.  Then people can offer advice as to what you are doing wrong, and where to look for an answer.  @the_wizard's post is good as well.  Map Reduce would make things run a lot faster.